# SQL Server 2005 Report Services only works on development

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I have a large number of reports that only seem to load when working with MS Visual Web Developer Express.  When I put application into production, all my reports just spin and then show nothing.

Answer (score 0):

We need a lot more information to give you a good answer. There are many reasons why this could happen. One possibility - the data source is different on the server than on your local PC. Keep in mind - when you deploy a report to a SQL Server Reporting Services server, and you overwrite an existing report, your newly deployed report will keep the old data source of the report you're overwriting; It will not automatically use the datasource you were using on your development machine if it was previously using something else.

Comment: I have checked the data source and all is fine there.  To further explain, on the development machine when I select a report, it displays the standard "save" dialog (in this case creating PDF files) but when using production app, it spins a while and then gives the standard IE warning (I pick Download file) and then it ends.  I am thinking the report is "empty"?

Comment: Furthermore, these are reports which have worked on the product server for quite some time (I have even restored the previous report folder) and it still acts the same.

Comment: Additional information, some users are able to get to the same reports just fine so I am curious if the issue is with some security settings in IE8 that is preventing it from working on production (the users who CAN get it are on IE7)   To recap, in my case the "Save dialog" never appears to save the report - on the ones that ARE working this dialog DOES appear.

Comment: @Mike Erickson - Yeah, it sounds like an IE configuration issue. I'll keep thinking about how to solve it. In the meantime, you may get more helpful answers from other people if you edit your original question to include the information you posted here as comments. This will make your question easier to read for people who don't scroll down, and will also "bump" it back to the top of the recent questions list on the homepage.

Answer (score 0):

Check in profiler if the Database dou think is accessed is accessed by reportserver.

If not check the datasource in http://yourreportserver/reports/

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried running IE8 in compatability mode?

Answer (score 0):

@mike, as you said, while you already check and recheck the data source but still some user can use the report, and some other dont.

Lets have some scenario. User A work on PC A001 can use the report, while user B, work on PC B001 cannot use the report.
Please recheck whether user A still able to use the report in PC B001? if that the case, the problem is in the user right. but if not the problem is in IE/machine configuration.

hope that helps.